# UIWebView release causes crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController subclass that has a UIWebView. It adds that web view as it's view's subviews and in dealloc releases it. Here's the relevant code:

```
#import "MediaVC.h"

@implementation MediaVC
@synthesize file, repository, server, delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    [webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [webView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    [[self view] addSubview:webView];

    [self displayFile];


    [flex release];
    [buttonDone release];
    [buttonAction release];
}


- (void)displayFile {

    if (!mimeString) {
        [webView loadData:nil 
                 MIMEType:nil 
         textEncodingName:nil 
                  baseURL:nil];


        [SVProgressHUD dismissWithError:@"Can't display this file." afterDelay:2];
    } else {

        [[DataCenter sharedInstance] getDataForFile:file 
                                             server:server 
                                         repository:repository 
                                            isThumb:NO
                                         completion:^(NSData *data) {

                                             NSString *filenamePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.%@", [[file path] pathExtension]];
                                             NSString *docDir = [DataCenter getDocumentsDirectoryPath];

                                             NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filenamePath];

                                             [data writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

                                             [webView loadData:data 
                                                      MIMEType:[DataCenter mimeTypeForFile:file]
                                              textEncodingName:nil 
                                                       baseURL:nil];

                                             if (!data) {
                                                 [SVProgressHUD dismissWithError:@"Error!"];
                                             } else {
                                                 [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                             }

                                         } progress:^(float progress) {
                                             [SVProgressHUD setFloat:progress];
                                         }];


    }

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [buttonNext release];
    [buttonBack release];
    //[webView release]; ---CRASH HAPPENS IF I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The app crashes at [super dealloc];. I have NSZombieEnabled and it doesn't give me any error regarding "error sent to deallocated instance....". What I did find is that if I comment out `[webView release],` the crash doesn't happen.
I check, and I am only allocating UIWebView once and releasing it once.

**UPDATE** Please find the complete class below. As i said, there's a lot in that class that's not relevant and I couldn't find any problem in it, maybe you guys find something:

```
#import "MediaVC.h"
#import "DataCenter.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "File.h"

@implementation MediaVC
@synthesize file, repository, server, delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                target:self 
                                                                                action:@selector(done)];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                                  target:self 
                                                                                  action:@selector(action:)];


    buttonNext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" 
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                 target:self 
                                                 action:@selector(next)];

    buttonBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                 target:self 
                                                 action:@selector(back)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                          target:nil 
                                                                          action:nil];


    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:buttonDone];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:buttonAction];
    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO];
    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonBack, flex, buttonNext, nil] animated:YES];



    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    [webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [webView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    [[self view] addSubview:webView];

    [self displayFile];


    [flex release];
    [buttonDone release];
    [buttonAction release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)done {
    [delegate doneMediaVC:self];
}

- (void)action:(id)button {
    NSString *filenamePath = [file path];
    NSString *docDir = [DataCenter getDocumentsDirectoryPath];

    NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filenamePath];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *c = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    BOOL success = [c presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:buttonBack animated:YES];
    if (!success) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"An application cannt be found to open this file" 
                                                           delegate:nil 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }
}

- (void)displayFile {

    [self setTitle:[file name]];

    [SVProgressHUD showInView:[[self navigationController] view] 
                       status:@"Loading..." 
             networkIndicator:YES
                     progress:YES];

    NSString *mimeString = [DataCenter mimeTypeForFile:file];


    if (!mimeString) {
        [webView loadData:nil 
                 MIMEType:nil 
         textEncodingName:nil 
                  baseURL:nil];


        [SVProgressHUD dismissWithError:@"Can't display this file." afterDelay:2];
    } else {

        [[DataCenter sharedInstance] getDataForFile:file 
                                             server:server 
                                         repository:repository 
                                            isThumb:NO
                                         completion:^(NSData *data) {

                                             NSString *filenamePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.%@", [[file path] pathExtension]];
                                             NSString *docDir = [DataCenter getDocumentsDirectoryPath];

                                             NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filenamePath];

                                             [data writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

                                             [webView loadData:data 
                                                      MIMEType:[DataCenter mimeTypeForFile:file]
                                              textEncodingName:nil 
                                                       baseURL:nil];

                                             if (!data) {
                                                 [SVProgressHUD dismissWithError:@"Error!"];
                                             } else {
                                                 [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                             }

                                         } progress:^(float progress) {
                                             [SVProgressHUD setFloat:progress];
                                         }];


    }

    if (![delegate canGoNext:self currentFile:file]) {
        [buttonNext setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [buttonNext setEnabled:YES];
    }


    if (![delegate canGoPrevious:self currentFile:file]) {
        [buttonBack setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [buttonBack setEnabled:YES];
    }
}

- (void)back {
    [self setFile:[delegate getPreviousFileForMediaVC:self currentFile:file]];
    [self displayFile];
}

- (void)next {
    [self setFile:[delegate getNextFileForMediaVC:self currentFile:file]];
    [self displayFile];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [buttonNext release];
    [buttonBack release];
    //[webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the allocation and release of the webview variable. Maybe you created a retained property mapped to webview? If not, something else must be causing the crash.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert looking at the amount of code that's missing, a lot can be wrong with the actual code.

Comment: I know, that's why I said there's nothing wrong with the alloc/release of the variable, and something else is probably causing the problem.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert well, there is, since you should set the delegate to nil before releasing the webview variable.

Comment: I just pasted amy complete class in original question.

Comment: @PragmaOnce could you show the header file as well? Are you doing any fancy stuff with UIWebView (like adding a category?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you see this line in the documentation?

> Important Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have
>   set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to nil. This
>   can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.

Your "relevant code" doesn't show you setting the delegate, but then again, your relevant code is not complete at all. (flex? buttonDone? buttonAction?)

Please share *all* code if you want a good answer.

Comment: I just pasted amy complete class in original question.